# Telethon Telegram workers are too busy to respond immediately (caused by SendMultiMediaRequest)

Tags: python, telethon

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Ijh.png)
I'm getting this warning every time when my reposter sends a post from one channel to another and this post contains more than 8 media files. If it has more than 8, it will divide my post: first post - 8 media files and second one - 1-2 media files without text(it is left in the first part)
[sending message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OPiv.png)
How can I fix it? I want to get rid of warning and dividing post from another channer to separate ones if it has more than 8 media files

I tried everything,

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, "Telegram is having internal issues". This means the issue is outside of your control and can't really "fix" it.

The library automatically retries a few times by default. You can turn this off if you want to handle the error yourself. You can also check `logging`'s documentation to learn how to filter out messages if all you want is to "turn off" the warning from being printed.